EEException: User memory limit exceeded calculating seasonal NDVI over 40 years
I am new to GEE and definitely not an expert in Python. I have been trying to navigate the memory exceeded error here for processing 40 years of EVI images where each year is aggregated into hurricane and non-hurricane seasons (i.e., 40 years, each year has 2 images, each representing a season).
How do I make this code use less memory?
 #get dataset from GEE data catalogue and filter by date, ROI, cloud cover
    landsat_data_85to12 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2").filterDate('1985-01-01', '2012-12-31').filterBounds(city_extent)
    data_85to12 = landsat_data_85to12.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',30).filterMetadata('IMAGE_QUALITY','equals',9)
    
    landsat_data_13to24 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterDate('2013-01-01', '2024-08-31').filterBounds(city_extent)
    data_13to24 = landsat_data_13to24.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',30).filterMetadata('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI','equals',9)
    
    #Preprocessing
    # Cloud masking function for both Landsat 5 and Landsat 8
    def mask_clouds(image):
        saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0)
        qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
        qaMask = qa.bitwiseAnd(8).eq(0).And(qa.bitwiseAnd(16).eq(0)).And(qa.bitwiseAnd(32).eq(0))
        
        return image.updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
    
    # Apply the cloud mask function to the ImageCollection
    masked_85to12 = data_85to12.map(mask_clouds)
    masked_13to24 = data_13to24.map(mask_clouds)
    
    #EVI Calculations 
    def calculate_evi(image, bands):
        evi = ((image.select(bands[0]).subtract(image.select(bands[1])))
                .divide(image.select(bands[0]).add(image.select(bands[1]).multiply(6))
                        .subtract(image.select(bands[2]).multiply(7.5)).add(1))).multiply(2.5).rename('EVI') 
        
        return ee.Image(evi).set({
            'system:time_start': image.date().millis(),          
            'system:index': image.get('system:index'),
            'acquisition_date': image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED')  
        })
     
    def calculate_evi_5(image):
        return calculate_evi(image, ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B1'])
    
    def calculate_evi_8(image):
        return calculate_evi(image, ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B2'])
    
    #Calculate Seasonal (Hurricane and Post-Hurricane) Means 
    def calculate_mean_index(image_col, start_month, end_month, year):
        """Calculate mean Index for a specified image collection and time period."""
        
        year = ee.Number(year)
        
        # Filter images by year and month
        filtered = image_col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')).filter(
            ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_month, end_month, 'month')
        )
    
         # Count the number of filtered images
        image_count = filtered.size() 
    
        # Check if there are valid images 
        if image_count.gt(0):  
            
            return filtered.mean().set({
                'year': year,
                'month_range': f'{start_month}-{end_month}', 
                'system:time_start': ee.Date.fromYMD(year, start_month, 1).millis()
            })
        else:
            print(f"No images found for {year} {start_month}-{end_month}.")
            return None
    
    
    # Functions to calculate mean index for hurricane and post-hurricane seasons
    def calculate_hurricane_mean(year, image_collection):
        year = ee.Number(year)
        return calculate_mean_index(image_collection, 6, 11, year)   # Calculate mean for June to November
    
    def calculate_post_hurricane_mean(year, image_collection, index_type):
        year = ee.Number(year)
        
        # Calculate mean for December to May
        mean_post_hurricane_dec = calculate_mean_index(image_collection, 12, 12, year)  # December  
        mean_post_hurricane_jan_to_may = calculate_mean_index(image_collection, 1, 5, year.add(1))  # Jan to May of next year 
    
        mean_index = ee.ImageCollection([mean_post_hurricane_dec, mean_post_hurricane_jan_to_may]).mean()
    
        if index_type == 'NDVI':
            mean_index = mean_index.rename('NDVI')
        elif index_type == 'EVI':
            mean_index = mean_index.rename('EVI')
    
        return ee.Image(mean_index).set({
            'year_start': year,
            'year_end': year.add(1),
            'month_range': '12-5', 
            'system:time_start': ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 12, 1).millis()
        }) 
    
    # Function to process years for both hurricane and post-hurricane seasons
    def process_years_in_batches(start_year, end_year, batch_size, image_collection, index_type):
        hurricane_results = []
        post_hurricane_results = []
    
        for batch_start in range(start_year, end_year + 1, batch_size):
            batch_end = min(batch_start + batch_size - 1, end_year)
            years = ee.List.sequence(batch_start, batch_end)  # Create a list of years for the current batch
    
            # Calculate means for hurricane season for this batch
            hurricane_mean_results = years.map(lambda year: calculate_hurricane_mean(year, image_collection))  # Pass image_collection
            hurricane_results.append(hurricane_mean_results)  
    
            # Calculate means for post-hurricane season for this batch
            post_hurricane_mean_results = years.map(lambda year: calculate_post_hurricane_mean(year, image_collection, index_type))  # Pass image_collection
            post_hurricane_results.append(post_hurricane_mean_results)  
            
        return ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(hurricane_results).flatten()), ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(post_hurricane_results).flatten())
    
    #Calculate yearly changes between hurricane and post hurricane 
    def calculate_evi_change_for_year(year, hurricane_ic, post_hurricane_ic):
        year = ee.Number(year)
        
        # Get the EVI images for the respective year
        hurricane_evi = hurricane_ic.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')).first()
        post_hurricane_evi = post_hurricane_ic.filter(ee.Filter.equals('year_start', year)).first()
    
        # Calculate pixel-wise EVI change only if both images are valid
        if hurricane_evi and post_hurricane_evi:
            return ee.Image(post_hurricane_evi.subtract(hurricane_evi)).rename('EVI_Change')
        else:
            return None  
    
    # Function to process change between hurricane and post-hurricane seasons
    def process_change_in_batches(start_year, end_year, batch_size, hurricane_ic, post_hurricane_ic):
        evi_changes_ic = []
    
        for batch_start in range(start_year, end_year + 1, batch_size):
            batch_end = min(batch_start + batch_size - 1, end_year)
            years = ee.List.sequence(batch_start, batch_end)  # Create a list of years for the current batch
    
            # Calculate evi change between hurricane and post hurricane season
            changes_ic = years.map(lambda year: calculate_evi_change_for_year(year, hurricane_ic, post_hurricane_ic))
            evi_changes_ic.append(changes_ic)  
            
        return ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(evi_changes_ic).flatten())
    
    #Apply the EVI function to the ImageCollection
    evi_85to12 = masked_85to12.map(calculate_evi_5).map(lambda image: image.clip(city_extent))
    evi_13to24 = masked_13to24.map(calculate_evi_8).map(lambda image: image.clip(city_extent))
    masked_85to12 = None
    masked_13to24 = None
    evi_collection  = evi_85to12.merge(evi_13to24)
    
    # Process the years from 1985 to 2024 in chunks of 10 years
    evi_hurricane_results, evi_post_hurricane_results = process_years_in_batches(1985, 2024, 10, evi_collection, index_type='EVI')
    #Apply the EVI function to the ImageCollection
    evi_85to12 = masked_85to12.map(calculate_evi_5).map(lambda image: image.clip(city_extent))
    evi_13to24 = masked_13to24.map(calculate_evi_8).map(lambda image: image.clip(city_extent))
    masked_85to12 = None
    masked_13to24 = None
    evi_collection  = evi_85to12.merge(evi_13to24)
    
    # Process the years from 1985 to 2024 in chunks of 10 years
    evi_hurricane_results, evi_post_hurricane_results = process_years_in_batches(1985, 2024, 10, evi_collection, index_type='EVI')
    Map.addLayer(evi_difference_results.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31').first(), 
                 {'min': -1, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['blue', 'white', 'green']},"2020 EVI Change")
    
    # Display the map
    Map

